# Connecting to HTTP server hosted on windows via LAN

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall

I'm attempting to host a simple http server on my Windows machine using python's http.server module. I start the server, host it at the port 8888 and I can connect to `localhost:8888`. But when I try to connect to it via LAN, I can't reach the site. Naturally, I assumed the firewall was blocking the access and created an inbound rule allowing TCP connections on the port 8888. This didn't fix it. I checked if I can ping my windows machine from devices in the same network and I can, after adding an inbound rule for file and printer sharing. I attempted various things: disabling all network connections except the one connected to the router, checking out the log files and disabling firewall completely, none of it worked so I'd be grateful if someone could point me in direction where to look next.

The log files are filled with entries like this:

```
#Fields: date time action protocol src-ip dst-ip src-port dst-port size tcpflags tcpsyn tcpack tcpwin icmptype icmpcode info path

2020-03-23 19:01:33 DROP UDP 192.168.0.17 224.0.0.251 5353 5353 105 - - - - - - - RECEIVE
```

I did try changing the rule I created in the firewall to allow UDP connections, but that didn't help either.

Interestingly, if I host the server over ubuntu on windows it works well, but I would like be able to host it independently of it.

Comment: I opened the actions properties on the advanced settings and set the firewall state to off for all three (domain, private, public) profiles, the issue is still here

Comment: What IP is it listening to?

Comment: Ah, it looks like the issue was in my python configuration. The default address binding on linux is `0.0.0.0`, whereas on windows it's just `[::]`. When I set it explicitly to `0.0.0.0` it worked. Thank you for the question as it lead me to the solution, feel free to post it as the answer and I'll accept it.